# linter-jslint for atom - how do I configure it?

Tags: atom-editor, jslint, linter

I have recently started using the linter-jslint plugin for atom and there are a few issues that I would like to override.
Things like setting it up so that it doesn't say "unexpected 'this'" and the like.

However try as I may, I cannot find any documentation that explains (at least for a novice like myself) how to set this up. There isn't a settings page within atom that talks directly to the linter and the only stuff I can find via google is related to JSHint.

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: I appreciate that alot of explanation is already done in the thread you linked, however does this still apply to making edits within Atom? There is no mention of it within that thread. This may seem obvious but I'm very inexperienced with configuring text editors, I haven't been working with them for very long.

Comment: Yes, `linter-jslint` basically integrates JSLint into Atom, so to configure JSLint, you can refer to that link. I prefer the way you can configure `jshint` or `eslint`, but it seems JSLint doesn't offer that.

Comment: With the atom-editor tag, this *is* a different question (fwiw, I'm the guy with the accepted answer at the "duplicate" question). The feature exists in Sublime Text, JSLint for VS, etc, and OP asks how to set up a config file *in Atom*. Moreover, that seems possible! [This page](https://atom.io/packages/jslint) says: "`JSlint options can be configured via .jslintrc config files, located in 1.) your home directory (global options) and 2.) your project root directory (project specific options).`" Might be worth trying that package if linter-jslint doesn't allow it.

Comment: Even for linter-jslint, [the docs](https://atom.io/packages/linter-jslint) say there's an option to, "`Disable linter when no .jslintrc is found in project `" So try dropping one in your project's root and see what happens! Though also see [this bug report](https://github.com/jlsalvador/linter-jslint/issues/4). So it's at least intended to be a feature.